# updating elements in primefaces with spring webflow

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

I'm wondering what is proper way to update elements on my page after event from another element. Lets say I have stateless bean which use services to get data for me, and I have scoped bean which is data model for my elements, scoped bean gets data when flow start in evaluate element from stateless bean. And now how should I get new data from stateless bean to scoped bean and re render elements with new values? Use remote command? It depends on elements? I hope YOu will get my point. I will appreciate any help, samples, whatever :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work with jsf+spring, but you can trye following:

```
public class MyScopedBean {

    @Autowired
    private MyStatelessBean statelessBean;

    private String someProperty;

    // getter, setter for someProperty
    // ...

    public void update() {
        someProperty = statelessBean.getDataFrowAnywhere();
    }
}
```

On you page:

```
<p:outputText id="foo" value="#{scopedBean.someProperty}"/>
<p:commandButton action="#{scopedBean.updateData}" update="foo"/>
```

Comment: I was considering this way and it work fine, thanks for this. Wondering if there is more "workflow way" :)